# ARM: best way to combine two registers holding halves of a 32-bit value into a destination register

Tags: assembly, arm

suppose I have three uint32_t values in `r0`, `r1` and `r2`; suppose that I have a constant `shift` in the range of `[0, 32]`

Here's C code that I need to do:

```
uint32_t rx = (r0 >> shift) | (r1 << (32 - shift));
uint32_t ry = (r1 >> shift) | (r2 << (32 - shift));
```

What ARM instructions do I need to use? I need it done in 1 or two instructions only.
If `shift` is 16, then it's easy:

```
PKHTB  rx, r0, r1
PKHBT  ry, r1, r2
```

What about if shift is 8 or 24 bits?
Basically, I have unaligned pointer and I need to read words from that unaligned pointer. At first, I want to clear two least significant bits (make it 4-byte aligned) and then read words using that pointer and do some shuffling to get what I need in registers sequentially.

NOTE: I don't need workarounds or other suggestions. I need to get words from unaligned pointer. I can't modify U or A bits, unaligned read crashes the app.

Comment: "I don't need workarounds or other suggestions" is pretty rude FYI. And yes, I know you didn't need this suggestion :) Go read up on XY problem.

Comment: you may say that I have XY problem, but I don't want to know anything other the Y solution. Clear? I made it clear, because I knew I may get useless suggestions that arm can do unaligned reads etc. I know that and that's unrelated to what I ask.

Comment: You did not explain why you need "two instructions only". You did not mention your actual hardware and why you can't enable unaligned reads. You did not say why memcpy is not suitable for you. And so on. Just because you think this is the solution to your overall problem doesn't mean it's the only solution.

Comment: I do 16x16 byte SAD and I do unaligned reads for armv6, but I have special emulator that I need to support and it's a buggy pile of manure, so the only way is to do unaligned reads and combine that stuff into registers so I could use USADA8 instruction. Simply because of that one op-code no other solution can be better.

Comment: By the way, it would be that XY problem: I should have asked how to enable that junk emulator from arm to work properly, but they are silent on that. So far, all pro-tools for c++ seemed to me like broken shit compared to tools from MS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this sort of thing should work, though I've not tested it:

```
BFI  rx, r0, #8, #24
BFI  ry, r1, #8, #24
UBFX r1, r1, #24, #8
BFI  rx, r1, #0, #8
UBFX r2, r2, #24, #8
BFI  ry, r2, #0, #8
```

or

```
BFI  rx, r0, #24, #8
BFI  ry, r1, #24, #8
UBFX r1, r1, #8, #24
BFI  rx, r1, #0, #24
UBFX r2, r2, #8, #24
BFI  ry, r2, #0, #24
```

I don't think it can be done in 1 or two instructions only. The UBFX could be replaced with a right shift, if you like that better.

Note that some ARM architectures *do* support unaligned loads.

EDIT: This has been bugging me. There has to be a better way and I think I found it now:

```
@ shift is one of {8, 16, 24}
lsr     rx, r0, #\shift
orr     rx, rx, r1, lsl #32-\shift
lsr     ry, r1, #\shift
orr     ry, ry, r2, lsl #32-\shift
```

`r0` can be used as a destination register in place of `rx`, same for `r1`/`ry`

Comment: this is 2 ins per word (obviously it's impossible to get 2 words in more than two instructions), that's what I was looking for. I simply don't get it: who writes that pretty useless docs at arm. Their manuals are meant to be read in parallel with a book? I couldn't get what exactly that BFI does and the only way is to test and see results. On android, I can't test, retarded build system makes it overly obscure and impossible to set proper compier/assembler flags.

Comment: Surprising, but it's not possible to combine into one word using two BFI instructions. The reason is because r1's high part cannot be put into lowest byte of the destination word. It seems like it requires 3 instructions per load, or some other opcodes are needed

Comment: Doh! I should have spotted that. Of course, you need a shift as well, but only for the r1 and r2, not for r0. :(

Comment: Ok, I've just edited my answer to add bitfield extracts for the high-order bits.

Comment: I think the original solution might work if I switch to big-endian reads. I need to realign bytes to be able to use USADA8, and there is no difference if I use big-endian or little endian memory access. I'll test to see if it helps. Otherwise, I think it's just better use regular shifts to do it in 3 ops per word.

Comment: Oh, I'm wrong, if I use `SETEND  BE`, then reads from another pointer that I do in parallel will also contain reversed bytes and the problem will still be the same.

Comment: At the end I came to conclusion that there is absolutely no value in these UBFX BFI or PKHTB. Probably these were invented for something else. Regular shifts is the way to go: two ops per word. PKHTB cannot be used at all to get one word per 1 ins.

Comment: Unless I'm very much mistaken (again), I think I've cracked it this time. I've updated my answer with a new solution.

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned that regular shifts is the best solution here without posting actual asm code. I updated the answer with better sequence: lsr rx, r0, #8 ; orr rx, rx, r1, lsl #24

Comment: Right, that comes to the same thing. :)